# Send non executable script in body by mailto:

Tags: javascript, mailto

I want to prepare an email to send with mailto:
This email contains a few words and a js script. This script does not need to be executed. It's just for the receiver to copy and paste.

The script :

```
<script id="myID">var script = document.createElement("script");script.src="script-to-inject.js?id=myID&type=0&name=Name&size=120";document.head.appendChild(script); </script>
```

And my mailto:

```
window.location.href = "mailto:"+email+"?subject="+subject+"&body=FewWords"+ script;
```

When my mail isopen i have something like that :

`<script id="myID">var script = document.createElement("script");script.src="script-to-inject.js?id=myID`

The end of the script does not appear (after the first `&`)

How can i fix this ?
Thanks !

Comment: You need to be escaping `email`, `subject`, and `script` properly when setting the `href` attribute. What if these variables contain the `&` or the `=` characters? You can see how this would get misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be escaping email, subject, and script properly when setting the href attribute. What if these variables contain the `&` or the `=` characters? You can see how this would get misinterpreted.

Try this:

```
window.location.href = "mailto:"
  + encodeURIComponent(email)
  + "?subject="
  + encodeURIComponent(subject)
  + "&body=FewWords"
  + encodeURIComponent(script);
```

(I'm not sure that you can pass HTML in the `body` parameter, by the way, it might get interpreted as plain text.)

You can also use `URLSearchParams`:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('subject', subject);
params.append('body', 'FewWords' + script);
window.location.href = 'mailto:' + encodeURIComponent(email) + '?' + params.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks it was obvious ... I'm dumb ahah

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to encode the URL parameters, so the `&` starts the next parameter.

You can use the `encodeURIComponent` function:

```js
window.location.href = "mailto:" + encodeURIComponent(email) +
  "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent(subject) +
  "&body=" + encodeURIComponent("FewWords" + script);
```

Another, cleaner, way would be to use `URLSearchParams`:

```js
const url = new URL(`mailto:${encodeURIComponent(email)}`)
url.searchParams.set('subject', subject)
url.searchParams.set('body', 'FewWords' + script)
window.location.href = url
```

Comment: Thanks it was obvious ... I'm dumb ahah